Why fix the probability current, and change the density, instead of vice versa in the Klein Gordon equation
I was reading this post: Finding the expression for probability density (the Klein Gordon equation)
while trying to understand the difficulties that arise when finding a probability current continuity equation and am confused. In all the sources I have read say something along the lines of "let us assume the probability current" $j$ remains in the same form in the Schrödinger equation, and then figure out what the probability density $\rho$ must be to make the continuity equation hold". They then arrive at a probability density $\rho(x)=\mathrm{i}\left[\phi^*(x) \frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \phi^*(x)}{\partial t} \phi(x)\right]$ that can be negative, and is thus unphysical. $j$ remains the same as $\boldsymbol{j}(x)=-\mathrm{i}\left[\phi^*(x)\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi(x)-\phi(x)\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi^*(x)\right]$. Why do we not simply define $\rho = \phi ^ *\phi$, and then figure out what $j$ must be for the continuity equation to hold? This is what we did with the Schrödinger equation, and it worked well. In the end, unless I grossly understand how quantum mechanics works, $\phi^* \phi$ is by definition the probability density, so it seems strange to call it anything else.

As with many "why this, not that?" questions in physics, the answer is partly the maths precludes flavour X of that, partly that evidence precludes flavour Y of that.
Unlike the TDSE, the KGE is second-order in time, so its solutions are closed under complex conjugation, which multiplies the probability $3$-current by $-1$. The probability $4$-current you've encountered satisfies a Lorentz-invariant conservation law $\partial_\mu j^\mu=0$, which is just unitarity in the non-relativistic theory. It does mean, however, that $j^0$ also has a sign change under conjugation, so it can't be interpreted as the probability density of one particle. The most obvious definition of energy also changes sign.
If you think you can "fix" these issues, hold your horses; maybe I can convince you to embrace them instead.
This is why relativity forces quantum phenomena to apply to fields with particle and antiparticle quanta, and the KGE to describe a field rather than one particle, so $j^0$ is a charge density (under the convention that a particle has charge $+1$, which isn't fun when you study the electron/positron example). And before you know it we have the Dirac equation, which is first-order in time like the TDSE but still has negative-energy solutions, leading to a prediction of antimatter and - because the gamma matrices' anticommutation relations imply there are at least four of them - electrons being spin-$\tfrac12$, which had previously been an empirical fact you have to put into quantum mechanics by hand.
